# Populate array with random numbers efficiently

Tags: performance, vba, excel, random, memory-management

I have an initial Excel workbook with about `100 000` rows. I put those rows into array and then use that array to create `Client` class objects, which I add into a final array `resultColl`.

```
Function getClients(dataWorkbook As Workbook)
         ...
      With dataWorkbook.Worksheets(globals("DATA_SHEET"))

         tableArray = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, column_names), _
                            .Cells(lastRow, column_loss_ratio)).value

         For k = LBound(tableArray) To UBound(tableArray)
            Set clientCopy = New Client

            clientCopy.setClientName = tableArray(k, column_names)


            ...
            Set resultColl(k) = clientCopy
         Next
    End With

    getClients = resultColl
End Function
```

Then I use that array of `Client`s to run simulations, which means I run a `for` loop `N` times and generate a random number for each client `N` times:

```
Sub StartDataCollect()
    ...
    Dim clientsColl() As Client
    clientsColl = getClients(dataWorkbook)
    ...
    For simulation = 1 To globals("SIMULATION_COUNT")
        For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
            clientCopy.setSimulationCount = globals("SIMULATION_COUNT")
            clientCopy.generateRandom
        Next
    Next

    ...
End Sub
```

The `generateRandom` function:

```
Public Sub generateRandom()
    randomNumber = Rnd()
End Sub
```

So, all that happens in 1 simulation: VBA runs through an array of size `100 000`, puts a `Rnd()` inside each `Client` in that array.

The problem is, one iteration takes about a minute. Given I need to run at least `5 000` of them, it's a really long time. I'm not sure how to make it faster, since it doesn't seem too complicated to me already.

Comment: What is the point of the line `clientCopy.setSimulationCount = globals("SIMULATION_COUNT")` in your innermost loop? The simulation count is presumably a constant(ish), so you only need to set it once.

Comment: I’m downvoting because you’ve omitted portions of code from your question. This has resulted in the best answer being “the performance problem is in code you’ve not shown us”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop takes under 3 milliseconds on my PC - so your problem is somewhere else in your client class.

```
Sub testloop()
    Dim var(1 To 100000) As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    Dim dTime As Double

    dTime = microtimer
    For j = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
        var(j) = Rnd()
    Next j
    MsgBox (microtimer - dTime)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not direct answer to you question but refers to CPU performacne
based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393587(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
Private Enum ProcesPriority
    Idle = 64
    Normal = 32
    Realtime = 56
    High_priority = 128
    Below_Normal = 16384
    ABOVE_NORMAL = 32768
End Enum

Sub SetPriority_High
  SetPriority "Excel.exe", High_priority
End sub


Sub SetPriority(ByVal appName As String, ByVal priority As Long)
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & appName & "'")
For Each objProcess in colProcesses
    objProcess.SetPriority(BELOW_NORMAL)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to polute m*n matrix considering performance. This idea may not generate pure random number but you can implement it, if you like in your favorite language.

```
array x[4*n]
for i=0 to 4*n                 //polute this array with random numbers
   x[i] = random()

for i=0 to m
   z = rand()                 //now choose a random offset value
   for j=0 to n
      mat[i][j] = x[(j+z)%n]
```